# Как узнать к каким данным в базе Postgres получает доступ программа в процессе работы

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql9.5

Программа установлена вместе с базой Postgres sql 8.4 и использует данные, записанные в базе Postgres.
Мне говорили, что можно перехватывать sql-запросы программы и записывать их.
Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно включить журналирование в конфиге:

log_statement = 'all'

https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/runtime-config-logging.html#guc-log-statement